# How to count the frequency of two words appearing together in the same column across multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of investors for companies 1-500 each divided into its own sheet. I would like to count how many times "investor A" and "Investor B" appear in the same column across the whole document IE how often "Investor A" and "investor B" both invested in the same company.

Comment: Use user-defined function. Or normalize your data (maybe move it to some database - MS Access for example).

Comment: You have 500 sheets?

Answer (score 2):

*`COUNTIF` wrapped with `SUMPRODUCT`, array (CSE) formula fixes the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Write Sheet Name somewhere in Master Sheet.
- Input Searh Values in two cells.
- Array formula in Cell `G47`.

  `{=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&E45:E47&"'!A:B"),F45)+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&E45:E47&"'!A:B"),F46))}`

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Modify `Sheet list` and `Search Values` (criteria) as your need.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.